# Unit test Angular 1 (with typescript) controller

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I have a tiny project in Angular 1 using typescript and I'd like to make some unit tests using jasmine. Cool so far! Firstly, I wanna test my controller to make sure that when I call a method from there I will get the right response. Pretty simple, huh?!

I already got the controller instance and I'm able to access some scope variable values. However, when I attempt to call a method it does not work (I got undefined for the method). See codes below:

## Locate Controller:

```
/// <reference path="../../app.d.ts" />

module UnitTest {

    export class LocateController {

        private myLocation: any;
        private myLocationBkp: any;
        private now: Date;

        private searchForm: any;
        private urlRegex: any;

        constructor(private $scope: ng.IScope, 
            private $http: ng.IHttpService, 
            private $q: ng.IQService, 
            private $translate: ng.translate.ITranslateService,
            private locationService: LocationService) {

                this.myLocation = {};
        }

        /* Method responsible to return all information about the user. */
        public getMyLocation() {

            this.now = new Date();

            this.locationService.getMyLocation().then((data) => {
                this.myLocation = data;       
            });
        }

    }
}
app.controller('LocateController', ['$scope', '$http', '$q', '$translate', 'LocationService', UnitTest.LocateController]);
```

## Locate Service

```
/// <reference path="../../app.d.ts" />

module UnitTest {

    export class LocationService {

        /* ---- global variables ---- */
        private API_HOST: string = "http://freegeoip.net";

        constructor(private $http: ng.IHttpService,
            private $q: ng.IQService) {

        }


        /* Method responsible to retrieve user's location information  */
        public getMyLocation(): ng.IPromise<any> {

            var defer = this.$q.defer();
            $.ajax({
                type : 'GET'
               ,url : this.API_HOST + '/json/'

               ,success: (response) => {defer.resolve(response);}
               ,error: (error) => {defer.reject('Something went wrong: ' + error.responseText);} 
            });

            return defer.promise;
        }
    }
}

app.service("LocationService", ['$http', '$q', UnitTest.LocationService]);
```

## Controller Spec

```
/// <reference path="../app.d.ts" />

describe('Locate Controller', () => {
    var $rootScope;
    var scope;
    var $httpBackend;
    var ctrl = null;
    var locService;

    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('unittest'));
    beforeEach(inject((_$httpBackend_, $rootScope, _$controller_, LocationService) => {
        $httpBackend = _$httpBackend_;
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        locService = LocationService;
    }));

    it('should call getMyLocation method and change myLocation value', inject(($controller) => {
        ctrl = $controller('LocateController', {$scope: scope});
        ctrl.getMyLocation();
        expect(ctrl.myLocation).toEqual(''); // empty is the initial value. After calling the method it should be different of ''
    }));

});
```

Debugging my spec test code in Chrome, when I'm inspecting the call to method this is what is displayed: 
[see screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aUuY.png)

[why the method does not appear here?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95rdV.png)

I'm not sure if either the method was called correctly but I didn't wait for promise response or it is not being called properly. Therefore, help me to make it works, please!

If any additional information is needed, just let me know!

Comment: Because the method is asynchronous and does real HTTP request, which is a no-no in unit tests. There's no good reason to use $.ajax in Angular. Consider replacing it with $http and then test it as the manual suggests.

Comment: Hi @estus! Thanks for replying me! I already changed $ajax to $http. Now, how could I call the method and wait for promise response before reaching expect condition? Because ctrl.myLocation variable is not changing its value at all as expected.

Comment: Now $http request is supposed to be mocked with https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend , and the promise will be executed synchronously.